# Unable to Insert Data from Angular frontend to Laravel API whitch Model Relationship One to Many

Tags: angular, laravel, eloquent

I have Angular App connected with Laravel API. In Laravel API there are one to many relationship between Employee and Salary Models. when I try to insert data Only insert Employee Model data but not insert salary model data
Employee Insert Controller is

```
public function addEmployee(Request $request) {
        $employee = Employee::create($request->all());
        $salary = $employee->salaries()->create($request->all());
        return response($employee, 201);
}
```

api route for insert

```
/add new Employee
Route::post('addEmployee','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@addEmployee');
```

employee-add.html

```
<div class="detail-list">
    <h3>Employee Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="insertData()">
        <h4>Profile Detail</h4>
        
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.first_name">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.last_name">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="birth_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" name="birth_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.birth_date">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="hire_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Hire Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" name="hire_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.hire_date">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender">
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     
     <h4>Salary Details</h4>
     
     <div class="salary-details"  >
       <div class="table">
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="salary" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Salary</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.salary">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">From Date</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="date" name="from_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.from_date">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="to_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">To Date</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.to_date">
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
       </div>
     </div>
    
      
    <br>
    <button  class="btn btn-dark btn-sm mt-4 btnPosition">Add Employee</button>
    <br><br>
    </form>
```

angular data.service.ts for insert data

```
insertData(data: Employee) {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addEmployee', data);
  }
```

and employee-add.component.ts

```
export class EmployeeAddComponent implements OnInit {
  
  employees:any;
  employee = new Employee();
  salary: any;
  title: any;
  

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  

  insertData() {
    this.dataService.insertData(this.employee).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      
    })
    
  }

}
```

Employee model like

```
export class Employee {
    birth_date:any;
    first_name:any;
    last_name:any;
    gender:any;
    hire_date:any;
salaries: any;
salary:any;
emp_no: any;
}
```

but console encontered following error msg about salary
`ERROR TypeError: ctx.salary is undefined`
I think I need relationship between Employee Model and Salary Model in Angular? how could I fix this matter

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your API's Employee class (you only posted the Typescript class that Angular uses), but if I had to venture a guess, I would say you haven't defined the Employee.Salary as nullable.

Angular enforces script type checking, and so probably does your API.

To know for sure, try inserting an Employee using Postman (or API client other than Angular).  If you can insert it manually (without a salary) using Postman, but not using Angular, your issue is in your Angular code.  If not, then the problem is in your API code.

I run into this all the time, and for me the issue is that I'm sending data that doesn't conform to the API class definition.

Comment: yes I can insert data in postman successfully but problem with Angular

Comment: If Angular is sending null as the Salary, that could be the problem.  Try manually setting it to undefined instead.  Or simply don't include it.

Comment: yes I think problem is with this `<input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.salary">` I need how to send Employee Model related salary field to the inputs? but unable to do it